# Is possible get rtti info for types declarated in the implementation part of a different unit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rtti

I have several classes of a thirdparty component (which I cannot modify), Now I need to access to some classes declarated in the `implementation` part of that unit, The question : `Is possible get rtti info for types declarated in the implementation part of a external unit?` if not is possible exist another way to access such types? I know about the scope of the units and that the implementation declarations are private and only available within a specific Unit. but maybe exist some hack.

Comment: If you know they're in the implementation section then can't you just copy them to another unit and cast them as necessary?

Comment: why can you not modify the third party code? you have no source?

Comment: @WarrenP, Yes I have the source, but I cannot modify because is used in another unit without sourcecode.

Comment: So you can safely modify it but you can't safely add anything that would break binary compatibility with the other module. Adding a regular procedure or function (not a method) for example, should be safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  The RTTI generated for **implementation**-only classes is minimal, and probably not enough for you to perform RTTI Surgery with.

Best thing to do here is modify the source (please tell me you aren't using a library with no source available!) or if you really truly can't do that, then talk to the author.